# How can I put inside an array all ASCII values?

Tags: java

So basically I messed up.

```
private static char admittedLetters[] = {'L', 'K', 'M', 'C', 'U', 'Z', 'E', 'D'};
```

My entire program is kind of based around that array.
What I need is an array that has inside of it all 256 chars, you guys know of any way of doing that?

Edit: I need all 256 ascii chars for this to work:

```
 private Hashtable<Character, Integer> createFT() {

    int lettersRepetition[] = new int[admittedLetters.length];

    for (char character : text.toCharArray()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < admittedLetters.length; i++) {
            if (character == admittedLetters[i]) {
                lettersRepetition[i] = lettersRepetition[i] + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    Hashtable<Character, Integer> frequencyTable = new Hashtable<>();
    int cont = 0;
    for (char letter : admittedLetters) {
        frequencyTable.put(letter, lettersRepetition[cont]);
        cont++;
    }

    return frequencyTable;
}
```

I'm doing the huffman tree thing.

Comment: There are more than 255 characters in Java.

Comment: Does typing out all 255 characters that you need work for you? If not, why not?

Comment: This feels like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why do you need an array with "all" characters in it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch oh ok I just need all the ascii characters

Comment: Which 255 characters do you mean? Why not 256? Those with the ASCII values 0-255?

Comment: @azurefrog I just edited and explained

Comment: @Yunnosch yea thats what I meant the ascii values oops mb

Comment: You do not need an array with those characters. You need an array with one entry for each of the 256 ASCII characters, initialised with 0. That will allow you to count the occurences of each of those characters.

Comment: a `char` is also an integral type, not to hard to do a loop and use `(char) i` to get the character for that code... but having an array where each element is the same as its index is kind of useless (`array[i]` would be the same as `(char)i` if `char` is needed)

Comment: @Yunnosch k ill look into it ty

Comment: Idlyss. PueEw. Gl.

Comment: and a little trick to initialize an array with letters: `"LKMCUZED".toCharArray()` (ASCII consists of *only* 128 characters, 95 printable) - but what you need is just `lettersRepetition[character] += 1` (or `...++`) - index *conversion* to `int` is done by compiler

Comment: There are ASCII code points from 0 to 127 only, not 255.  So you only need an `int[]` with 128 entries.  Then increment the appropriate value in the array  `if (character <= 127)`.  You do _not_ need an array of characters to do this.

Comment: @Idon'tfeelsogood Well, it seemed like a reasonable question considering what little information we had to go on at the time. :-) Now we know more (what you're trying to achieve, the fact that this is a homework assignment, you actually mean ASCII characters 0-255, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of generating a list of characters then counting. just read the text and map all characters in the text.

```
 String  sourceText = "a whole bunch of characters and things like that";
    Map<Integer,Long> charCount = sourceText.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i->i,Collectors.counting()));
    charCount.forEach((k,v)->{
        char c = (char)k.intValue();
        System.out.println("the count for character `"+c+"` is:"+v);
    });
```

unfortunately from what i've looked at java doesn't like doing `Integer` to `Character` but it will do int to char and back primative. also it loses some type info so i couldn't do this in a 1 liner. but this just populates the map given the source text. and you can go in and remove newlines.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 128 ASCII characters. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). You could probably have meant ISO/IEC 8859-1, known in Java as ISO_8859_1. In any case the solution is as follows: Create an array of bytes with values 0 to 127 for ASCII or 255 for ISO-8859-1, and then convert it to a string: `String str = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);` (or respectively ISO_8859_1). To convert this string to an array of chars you could use either `getChars` or `chars`. See [the Javadoc for String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html).